# Missing/inconsistent River Thames map data in Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, rivers, waterways

I have noticed the River Thames cut off quite abruptly when applying the following query to Overpass:

```
(
  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

The resulting data is shown below - you can clearly see that the background map shows the river continuing, but the data does not follow that:

[image: River Thames data issue]

I've tried all the water types I can think of (below), but the best I get is a single line that follows the centre of the river, and not an area polygon that is topologically accurate.

```
(
  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  way["natural"="coastline"]({{bbox}});
  way["waterway"]({{bbox}});
  way["water"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

EDIT: This is the result of AndreJ's answer:

```
relation(2263653);>>;
out skel;
```

[image: Central line instead of area polygon(s)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The river Thames is too large to digitize it in one single Openstreetmap way element.

Therefore, a [relation](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2263653) is created to group all riverbanks belonging to it.

You can query that relation directly with Overpass Turbo, with no need to enter a bbox:

```
relation(2263653);>>;
out skel;
```

You can look up the relation ID for UK rivers at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/UK_Waterway_Relations following the links given there.

---

**Update**

The riverbank multipolygons are not included in the River Thames relation. Unfortunately, the multipolygons have no tags, the outer lines have `waterway=riverbank`, but the inner rings have other or no tags. You can get the correct riverbank only if you put all data of a larger bbox (or South England at least) into a Postgis database to sort that out.

Comment: This only seems to provide a line through the middle of the river, not a set of area polygons that match the background map data (see edited answer).

Comment: Sorry, I mean "see edited question"

Comment: I guess sparingly tagged multipolygons with holes are a bit too complicated for Overpass turbo.

Comment: Ah, thanks Andre. Your help is much appreciated, I'll accept the answer now.